# angular material 2 autocomplete asynchronous

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an angular 4 and an angular material 2. I want to use an autocomplete. In the first version, the angular material of the autocomplete supported the asymmetrical work.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete#asynchronous-results

Everything was great and very comfortable.
In the second version I tried to find a guide, but did not find anything.

[Angular 2 materials, autocomplete with remote data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308283/angular-2-materials-autocomplete-with-remote-data)

[How to use correctly autocomplete component from Angular2 MaterialDesign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879917/how-to-use-correctly-autocomplete-component-from-angular2-materialclean)

It does not count. They turn to the service for onInit. I need it on the click, as in the first version. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "They turn to the service for onInit"? If you want to make the call on a `click` event, then move the code block to a function that is called on `click` event. Those examples you listed in the question, make the call `onInit` because of this line `.startWith(null)`, so that user can see data as soon as they click the input field.

Here's an example:

html:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
           placeholder="Select Name"
           [formControl]="myCtrl" 
           (click)="getData()">
</md-input-container>
...
...
...
```

ts:

```
myCtrl: FormControl;

  filteredItems: any;

  items;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.myCtrl = new FormControl();
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  getData(){
    this.dataService.fetchData()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.items = data.customers;
          this.filteredItems = this.myCtrl.valueChanges
            .startWith(null)
            .map(i => i && i === 'object' ? i.name : i)
            .map(name => name ? this.filterItem(name) : this.items.slice());

        }
    );
  }

  filterItem(name) {
   return this.items.filter(item => new RegExp(`^${name}`, 'gi').test(item.name)); 
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/84QmOfdfczQoYbLPD6N2?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes!! This is what I need! Thank you!